# Python/Apache/Server - Can't import modules

Tags: python, apache, server

I have a executable python script that I want to run using apache. A simple print('hello') works fine, however it fails if the script imports some package. In this case it fails at 'import pandas'.

I'm using python version 3.5.2

I have installed pandas with pip3 install pandas, and the installation is successful. If I try again, I get:
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.10.0)

I have tried to start the script with both #! /usr/bin/python and #! /usr/bin/env python

Why could it be that it doesn't work? Is there some sort of step by step guide to manage this?

Comment: Does `#! /usr/bin/python3` work? I only ask because it looks like pip is aliased to pip3 and that's usually the convention

Comment: just tried, but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

These two optiones worked for me:
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas

or

sudo -H python3 -m pip install pandas